# Android LinearLayout.removeViewAt (int i) throws exceptions?

Tags: android

I have the following code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < linearLayout.getChildCount() - 5; i++) //IN this code, please assume the child count is 10;
{
    View v = linearLayout.getChildAt(i);
    Standard.Loge("REMOVING: " + i + " " + (v == null));
    linearLayout.removeViewAt(i);
}
```

This outputs the following:

```
REMOVING: 0 false
REMOVING: 1 false
REMOVING: 2 true
```

the app crashes, even though the views at index 2 - 4 have not been removed, throwing this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.unFocus(android.view.View)' on a null object reference
    at android.view.ViewGroup.removeViewInternal(ViewGroup.java:4937)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.removeViewAt(ViewGroup.java:4899)
    at (((The last line in the for loop above)))
```

It would appear that the views are null, even though getChildCount registers that the views exist, and my guess is that this is causing removeChildAt to crash. I am adding the views dynamically in java so I am not able to use findViewByID. I am really at a loss here. How can I fix this crash so I can remove these views?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you actually just want to remove element 0.  When you remove one of the elements, they all shift back.  So element 1 becomes 0 and 2 becomes 1, etc.

This code should work:

```
for (int i = 0; i < linearLayout.getChildCount() - 5; i++) //IN this code, please assume the child count is 10;
{
    View v = linearLayout.getChildAt(0);
    Standard.Loge("REMOVING: " + 0 + " " + (v == null));
    linearLayout.removeViewAt(0);
}
```

Comment: @chessdork: While it is not covered in this edition of the OP's question, in his original (now deleted) question, he has more than 5 child views.

Comment: The hours I spent on this simple problem... Thank you. It is funny, because I know how arrays work but this seems to have gone right over my head.

Answer (score 0):

If loop from 0 increase to 10 and remove the element, The element will be shift back.

Have some solution is start from 10 down to 0

```
val containerImg1 = viewForm.findViewById<RelativeLayout>(R.id.container_img_1)

for (index in containerImg1.childCount - 1 downTo 0) {
  val elem = containerImg1.getChildAt(index)
  if (elem.tag == "CIRCLE_RED") { /* some condition */
    containerImg1.removeView(elem)
  }
}
```